# Etymology is about the history of words, but is there a comparable word for the history of grammar?

Tags: grammar, etymology, history

Etymology is defined as "the study of the origin of words and the way in which their meanings have changed throughout history", but is there a similar name for the study of the history of grammar?

Comment: There is, but the search terms are "historical linguistics" and "syntactic change". A lot is known about what has happened, but not much about why.

Comment: @JohnLawler If you've got some supporting links for that, it'd be great to see an answer around it.

Comment: It's always better when the student does the research themself.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm honestly not that invested; this was just a passing thought. If you don't fancy writing an answer you don't need to - it just leaves this question in somewhat of a limbo state. I'm guessing you're the one who VTC'ed this question anyway. It would've been preferable if you'd have just asked what research I did beforehand, rather than assuming I did none.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word, itself, 'grammar' covers not only the subject but the discipline of the subject :

> In the West, grammar emerged as a discipline in Hellenism from the 3rd century BC

[Grammar Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar) [Under the heading 'History']

Comment: Yes, Grammar (meaning the grammar of Latin; anything written in Europe about grammar was written in Latin for 1500 years) was one of the Seven Liberal Arts. It's part of the Trivium (the Three Primary Arts: Grammar, Logic, and Rhetoric). These correspond to the modern fields of Syntax, Semantics, and Pragmatics. That's most of linguistics, outside of phonetics and phonology, but Aristotle didn't know about them; though they had recently been invented in India, he didn't read Sanskrit, either.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. I've pasted your note to myself to read up on, later.